# How to filter queryset by decimal stored in JSON?

Tags: django

I store some decimal's string representation in JSONField and want to filter by it.
Here's the model:

```
class Asset:
    cached_data = JSONField()
```

Content of JSONFields:

```
{
    "price": "123.456"
}
```

I tried a lot of ways to filter queryset by this value. The last one was

```
Asset.objects.annotate('price_as_decimal': Cast('cached_data__price', output_field=DecimalField())).filter(price_as_decimal__gt=100)
```

but it gives the error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "none"
```

while I'm sure there's a value for this key in the field

Comment: The annotate function does not use quote marks in the field, so remove them from "price_as_decimal". This maybe preventing the data to be converted to decimal, hence the data type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```py
Asset.objects.annotate(
    # 'price_as_decimal': Cast('cached_data__price', output_field=DecimalField())
    price_as_decimal=Cast('cached_data__price', output_field=DecimalField())
).filter(price_as_decimal__gt=100)
```

That seems to work fine, though the Django 4.2 documentation says to use the `KT` transform:

```py
Asset.objects.annotate(
    # 'price_as_decimal': Cast('cached_data__price', output_field=DecimalField())
    # price_as_decimal=Cast('cached_data__price', output_field=DecimalField())
    price_as_decimal=Cast(KT('cached_data__price'), output_field=DecimalField())
).filter(price_as_decimal__gt=100)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#kt-expressions